# Any linux version of clipboardfusion with macros

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I have [**Clipboardfusion**](http://www.clipboardfusion.com/) installed on my Windows computer and it has a macro feature that lets me create c# or vb macros that it will execute on the copied text in the clipboard.

Is there anything like this for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ClipIt](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clipit/).

> Execute actions with clipboard items